# Entra ID Protected Web app calling Entra ID protected api throwing unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

So i have looked over MS docs, other questions asked on here around Entra ID and setting up the program.cs but I am still getting an unauthorized error and when looking at whats returned when i call IDownstreamApi it appears to me its not sending the token.  Below is my Program.cs from both API and UI along with my appsettings.json.  With some redacted sections of course but same structure.

How I am calling the api

```
HttpResponseMessage value = await _DownstreamApi.CallApiForUserAsync("MyAPI", options => { options.BaseUrl = "https://localhost:7214/WeatherForecast"; }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Web App Program.cs

```
string[] initialScopes = builder.Configuration["GraphApi:Scopes"].Split(' ').AppendArray(builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"].Split(' '));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("EntraId"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("GraphApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
            .AddDownstreamApi("MyAPI", builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Web App appsettings.json

```
"EntraId": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "TenantId": "**WORKFLOW_REPLACE_TENANT**",
        "ClientId": "**WORKFLOW_REPLACE_CLIENT**",
        "ClientSecret": "**WORKFLOW_REPLACE_CLIENTSECRET**",
        "ClientCertificates": [
        ],
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    },
    "GraphApi": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
        "Scopes": "**GRAPHAPISCOPES**"
    },
    "DownstreamApi": {
        "BaseUrl": "**BASEAPIURL**",
        "Scopes": "**APISCOPES**"
    },
```

WebAPI Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("EntraId"));
```

WebAPI appsetting.json

```
"EntraId": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "TenantId": "**WORKFLOW_REPLACE_TENANT**",
        "ClientId": "**WORKFLOW_REPLACE_CLIENT**",
        "Scopes": "__Scopes__"
    }
```

UPDATE - 22-Aug-2023

I am following [MS Client app and API app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis) to the letter but still throwing not authorized.  I have a felling its something with the MS Identity Web but cannot say that factually as i have tried using IDownstreamAPI and manually creating the httpclient and neither work.